# TypeError for >> on float and int

Tags: python, python-3.3

I have some code below:

```
color = complexity * (255 / iterationCap)
r = (color >> 16) & 255
g = (color >> 8) & 255
b = (color >> 0) & 255
```

I am trying to calculate the color from a floating point number I get from the `color` variable.

Currently, I am using python 3.3 to try to shift the bits and `and` them with 255 to get the correct `r`, `g`, and `b` values.

The error I am getting is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'float' and 'int'
```

1. Is there an easy way to fix this? Like, can I shift floats with an int? And,
2. If not, is there an easy way to calculate color from a number?

Currently I am using the image library to draw pixels to a file and I just tack my color tuple on to an array, which I then feed into `Image.putdata(..)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 3 the `/` operator is a floating point division. You want to use `//` for integer division.

Given your comments about what the code is supposed to do we can write something like:

```
color = int(complexity * 255 / iterationCap) # gives an integer number from 0 to 255
r = color >> 16
g = color >> 8
b = color
```

That creates a gray gradient as complexity changes.

Comment: I need floating point division there though. It's not an option to change the first line.

Comment: So manually round to integers before bit shifting. Bit shifting for floats doesn't work.

Comment: I can't have integers in color unless it was calculated that way. So how about the second question? Since I can't shift floats, is there a way to calculate a RGB value from a float?

Comment: What's the range for `complexity` and `iterationCap`?

Comment: `iterationCap` I have at 100 and `complexity` goes from 0 to `iterationCap`

Comment: Alright, this is good. What about if I wanted something OFF the gray scale?

Answer (score 0):

```
color = long(complexity * (255 / iterationCap))
```

Since bit shifting floats is an undefined operation.

Answer (score 0):

Convert into an int before trying to attempt bitwise operations.

```
color = int(complexity * (255 / iterationCap))
```